# Problem with ClinCNV script

Tags: bed

I have some problems with ClinCNV:

My input: `Rscript /root/ClinCNV/clinCNV.R --normal /root/samples/final.cov --out /root/samples/ -bed /root/samples/fileGC.bed --folderWithScript /root/ClinCNV/`

And there is an output: `/root/ClinCNV/clinCNV.R: error: Error in getopt(spec = spec, opt = args) : short flag "b" is invalid`

I've already ask a question about ClinCNV and the main idea was to run script with absolute pathways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `-bed`. Multi-letter flags are usually set using `--` and not `-`. I don't know this particular program but since all other long options use `--`, and the only option with a `b` is your `-bed`, I suspect you just want `--bed` instead:

```
Rscript /root/ClinCNV/clinCNV.R --normal /root/samples/final.cov \
   --out /root/samples/ \
   --bed /root/samples/fileGC.bed \
   --folderWithScript /root/ClinCNV/
```

---

This is confirmed by the tool's [documentation](https://github.com/imgag/ClinCNV), actually:

> --bed - .bed file with coordinates of on-target regions, GC-annotated. Gene anotations in the last column can be used in output.

So yes, you need `--bed` and not `-bed`. Because you used `-`, the tool reads that as a single character flag (`-b`) with the value `ed` and doesn't know what to do with it.

---

On an unrelated note, you seem to be running these things as root which is a very, very bad idea. One bug in the program or one misconfiguration and you can mess up your entire system. I strongly urge you to never run commands as root unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Of course! It's now obvious `-b` or `--bed` would work. However `-bed` will not work @ИльяБетяев. Upvoted.